# Identify patterns leading to error in structured log files

Tags: machine-learning

I am currently working on parsed log data from IoT devices (log entries are batched every 15 minutes). All `info_*` / `err_*` are counts of the related log events:

```
| machine_id | timestamp           | os_ver | days_since_reboot | cpu_load | info_featA | info_featB | err_badrequests | err_timeoutrequests |
|------------|---------------------|--------|-------------------|----------|------------|------------|-----------------|---------------------|
| 1          | 2020-09-18 12:25:00 | 0.01   | 12                | 0.59     | 12         | 543        | 0               | 0                   |
| 1          | 2020-09-18 12:40:00 | 0.01   | 12                | 0.83     | 1          | 23         | 1               | 0                   |
| ...        | ...                 | ...    | ...               | ...      | ...        | ...        | ...             | ...                 |
| 2          | 2020-10-28 11:40:00 | 0.02   | 2                 | 0.12     | 43         | 54         | 0               | 1                   |
| 2          | 2020-10-28 11:55:00 | 0.02   | 2                 | 0.43     | 32         | 54         | 3               | 5                   |
| 2          | 2020-10-28 12:10:00 | 0.02   | 2                 | 0.23     | 0          | 4          | 0               | 23                  |
```

I am tasked to find some common patterns that might lead to an error event (e.g an increase in `info_featA` entries precedes a positive count in `err_badrequests`). For this reason I've thought to re-encode error columns into a boolean (`True` if `err_*` > 0) but I am fairly lost on the right approach to go about sequence analysis or finding the conditions that can lead to an error.

Also, error type is not very important for my problem as I just care about the **presence** of a positive error count (regardless of its type):

```
| machine_id | timestamp           | os_ver | days_since_reboot | cpu_load | info_featA | info_featB | has_err |
|------------|---------------------|--------|-------------------|----------|------------|------------|---------|
| 1          | 2020-09-18 12:25:00 | 0.01   | 12                | 0.59     | 12         | 543        | 0       |
| 1          | 2020-09-18 12:40:00 | 0.01   | 12                | 0.83     | 1          | 23         | 1       |
| ...        | ...                 | ...    | ...               | ...      | ...        | ...        | ...     |
| 2          | 2020-10-28 11:40:00 | 0.02   | 2                 | 0.12     | 43         | 54         | 0       |
| 2          | 2020-10-28 11:55:00 | 0.02   | 2                 | 0.43     | 32         | 54         | 1       |
| 2          | 2020-10-28 12:10:00 | 0.02   | 2                 | 0.23     | 0          | 4          | 0       |
```

At the moment I have created lagged variables (up to 2 hours before) to check if any lagged variable is somewhat correlated with error counts through a correlation matrix. I am pretty sure this is **not** the way to approach such problem.

---

The main goal is to identify (if any) some common patterns in the observed metrics that lead to an error.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to model this.

One option is to simplify the problem ignoring time. Fit a machine learning model that find the features that are associated with presence of errors.

Another option is treat this as [event-prediction in time series data](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-18476-0_24). In this case, it would be multivariate time series.